# Attach text to a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know there are 2 ways to do it. But none of them works for me.

The first way I tried is to create a gameObject and then put a cube(shape) and a canvas with Text in it. I set the position of shape, canvas(world space) and text to (0,0,0) so that they will stay together. However, Only the cube showed up. And disabling the cube still doesn't make the text display.

[image]

[image: Shape]

So I removed it and added Text Mesh to the shape and this required me to remove Mesh Filter. And now what I can see is only an empty space. Do I have any settings wrong?

[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused on what exactly you are trying to do?  Are you just trying to have floating text attached to an object that will always face the player? and be infront of the middle?

Comment: @Eddge Actually, my intention is to make a button with a gameobject instead of using UI button. If I use UI button, the gameobjects will not be on the same plane. The canvas is way above or below my game plane. And changing the canvas to world space will mess up the scale. I mean it will distort things. So I am struggling with creating a button that is on the same plane as my gameobjects.

Comment: why does it need to be on the same plane?  Should it appear behind other game objects? in the world or just behind the hud?

Comment: @Eddge Have you ever played Hearthstone? I hope I can make buttons like that and all those buttons are just like real objects instead of a 2D stuff.

Comment: I have not, I don't play alot of games anymore, just work on em =)

Comment: @Eddge The UI of Hearthstone is better than any other card game. That's one of the reasons why it is so popular. So it gives some inspirational ideas to make a better UI. It is a 3D game but displayed in the 2D way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do that with a `UI Button` game object and a 3D cube. The steps are as follows:

1. In your empty scene, create a 3D Cube.
2. After that, create a `UI Button` object.
3. Now that you have the button and the Canvas, drag the Canvas to become a child of the cube, like this:

   [image]
4. Now you have to set the Canvas to `World Space` render mode, remove the `Canvas Scaler` component, and set `Width = Height = 1` and all `Pos = 0`.
5. Final step, setup the Button: set `Width = Height = 100`, all `Scale = 0.01` and `Pos Z = -0.501`.

Now you have a perfectly functional button that will stay attached to the front face of the cube, no matter where the cube is positioned or rotated.

You can of course add as many buttons you want, and position them to different faces of the cube (even more than one button to a single face etc.).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have a small question. I used a grid layout in the other scene and I created a new scene to try your solution. And it seems that the grid layout stays so the posZ of the button can't be set to -0.5. It automatically becomes -1 or 0, which means the button doesn't stick to the cube. How do I solve that?

Comment: Simple: you don't use a `Grid Layout Group` component. ;) Making the buttons snap to pre-set values beats the intention of making them "stick" to a gameobject which should be free to move/rotate.
And another thing: if the number of buttons is high (i.e.: you have several game object with several buttons/UI elements in general on them), I'd avoid anyway the use of the UI system and adopt a trigger collider/raytracing system, for performance reasons (especially on mobile).

Comment: This is the most useful answer for myself this year. It clearly provides the usage of 2d elements in 3d. Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are misunderstanding a few things here, let me try to clear them up for you:

1. The use of **Canvas**:

A Canvas should (almost) always be a top-level object, meaning that it is not attached to any parent. Rather than that, the canvas serves as a parent to other objects, meaning that other objects are children of the canvas.

Also, having multiple canvas objects could cause you problems aswell, take a look at Panels and Layout Groups.

2. The difference between **Text Mesh** and **Text**:

A Text (or UI-Text) is an object that is inside a canvas to display text on the canvas space. A text *mesh* on the other hand is an object that is rendered inside your world, in 3D space, meaning it does (and probably should not) be attached to a Canvas object.

Comment: So do you have a solution for this? My first solution comes from this link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1185543/how-to-set-a-text-on-a-gameobject.html

Comment: Well ... I'm not sure whether I understand the full context of your question, but just try setting the canvas as the parent element, and putting all your other elements (the cube, the textmesh) inside the canvas.

Comment: Actually, my intention is to make a button with a gameobject instead of using UI button. If I use UI button, the gameobjects will not be on the same plane. The canvas is way above or below my game plane. And changing the canvas to world space will mess up the scale. I mean it will distort things. So I am struggling with creating a button that is on the same plane as my gameobjects.

Comment: Adding multiple canvases is the correct way to do things in 2021. Think of one canvas having static images and text and also constantly changing text(score, health, etc.) and images(health image, etc.). Put all the static objects on one canvas and you draw it only in Start. Have the rest in the Update. Efficiency and use fewer resources this way rather than draw everything all the time on one canvas.