# how to add text to the cube in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

How can i add this text to the cube : [image]

The cube is
[image: this is the cube]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach text to a gameobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469377/attach-text-to-a-gameobject)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question as defined in the help center.

Comment: @cigien it a programmig question ... u dont know anything about unity ... why u closed it

Comment: @Ruzihm Please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293806/8372853) post. For Unity questions, it is generally required that you have some code to show, and describe what issue you are facing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly you're looking for? If it's the text being a part of the cube, without it following the camera when you move like the other UI components, then you just need to set the render mode of the canvas on which your text is to World Space and place it where you want in the world.